# How to sort the list of objects by the values coming from array?

Tags: c#

I have a List products; with 100+ items.

For each item from the list I have product id.

And I have an array int[] sortedArray = {3,6,22,98,6,45,87};

I have to sort my product list and make order by productid, how it is in sortedArray. How can I implement that?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What is in `sortedArray`? Is it indices, or product IDs?

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach could be using `OrderBy` method by passing a `Func` which uses `IndexOf` method in order to sort the list based on the `sortedArray`.

```
list.OrderBy(s => sortedArray.IndexOf(s.ProductId)).ToList();
```

Comment: Watch out though - this is an `O(N^2.Log(N))` operation which is going to be nasty on large data sets.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, Then we could create a hash structure or dictionary in order to access the element with `O(1)`